# Obtenção de registos únicos baseado em duas colunas

Tags: r

Considerando o dataframe df1 pretendia obter um dataframe com registos únicos (origem, destino) contabilizando o nº de pares únicos (origem, destino) e somando o valor por par único:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    origem = c("A","A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
    destino=c("A","B","B","A", "A", "C","B"),
    valor=(c(1, 2,NA, 3, 0, 5,-1)))
```

Resultado pretendido:

```
  origem destino num_total valor_total
1      A       A         1           1
2      A       B         2           2
3      B       A         2           3
4      B       C         1           5
5      B       B         1          -1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com R base, pode usar `aggregate`. Para mais de uma função, pode unir o resultado de diferentes agregações:

```
agg <- merge(
  aggregate(df1[3], by = df1[1:2], length),
  aggregate(df1[3], by = df1[1:2], sum, na.rm = TRUE),
  by = c("origem", "destino"))

names(agg)[3:4] <- c("num_total", "valor_total")

agg
#>   origem destino num_total valor_total
#> 1      A       A         1           1
#> 2      A       B         2           2
#> 3      B       A         2           3
#> 4      B       B         1          -1
#> 5      B       C         1           5
```

Ou concatenar várias funções com `c`:

```
agg <- aggregate(df1$valor, by = df1[1:2], function(x) c(num_total = length(x), valor_total = sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Como apontado por @rui-barradas nos comentários, a concatenação vai resultar em uma variável `x` contendo uma matriz com os resultados. Para ter um *data.frame* apenas com colunas de vetores:

```
agg <- cbind(agg[-length(agg)], agg[[length(agg)]])

agg
#>   origem destino num_total valor_total
#> 1      A       A         1           1
#> 2      B       A         2           3
#> 3      A       B         2           2
#> 4      B       B         1          -1
#> 5      B       C         1           5
```

Pacotes como *dplyr* (usado na [resposta de Marcus Nunes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/522502/117168)) facilitam operações por grupo. Outra opção é *data.table*:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)

df1[, .(num_total = .N, valor_total = sum(valor, na.rm = TRUE)), .(origem, destino)]
#>    origem destino num_total valor_total
#> 1:      A       A         1           1
#> 2:      A       B         2           2
#> 3:      B       A         2           3
#> 4:      B       C         1           5
#> 5:      B       B         1          -1
```

Comment: Votei mas uma nota: se fizer `str(agg)` verá que a variável `x` é uma matriz, o resultado de `rbind` dos vetores produzidos pela função `c()`. Uma opção para ter um df só com vetores coluna é `agg<-aggregate(.)` seguido de `cbind(agg[-length(agg)], agg[[length(agg)]])`. Aqui é o método `cbind.data.frame` que é chamado, uma vez que `agg[-length(agg)]` é um df.

Comment: Obrigado, não havia observado esse detalhe. Editarei a resposta ASAP.

Answer (score 4):

Eu resolveria este problema da seguinte maneira:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  group_by(origem, destino) %>%
  summarise(num_total = n(),
            valor_total = sum(valor)) %>%
  ungroup()
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'origem'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>   origem destino num_total valor_total
#>   <chr>  <chr>       <int>       <dbl>
#> 1 A      A               1           1
#> 2 A      B               1           2
#> 3 B      A               2           3
#> 4 B      B               1          -1
#> 5 B      C               1           5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Explicando cada linha do código:

- `na.omit` é a função que remove as linhas com valores `NA`, pois elas não são necessárias para a soma final de ocorrências ou valores
- `group_by` é utilizada para agrupar os dados por origem e destino, fazendo com que as operações a partir daqui sejam aplicadas nos grupos criados
- `summarise` serve para resumir um conjunto de dados, aplicando a ele uma transformação que resultará em um número igual ou menor de linhas

  - `n()` conta as ocorrências de cada grupo (neste caso, pares de origem e destino)
  - `sum` soma os valores de cada par
- `ungroup` retira o agrupamento dos dados, mantendo um *tibble* simples como resposta

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar group_by e summarise da dplyr, com os comandos abaixo

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(
  origem = c("A","A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
  destino=c("A","B","B","A", "A", "C","B"),
  valor=(c(1, 2,NA, 3, 0, 5,-1)))
```

use o o group_by e summarise, e tem de usar na.rm = T para ignorar os NA quando estiver a somar

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(origem, destino) %>%
  summarise(num_total = n(),
            valor_total = sum(valor, na.rm = T))

print(df2) # fazer o print do novo dataframe
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   origem [2]
  origem destino num_total valor_total
  <chr>  <chr>       <int>       <dbl>
1 A      A               1           1
2 A      B               2           2
3 B      A               2           3
4 B      B               1          -1
5 B      C               1           5
```